# How do I find the coordinates an SVG line crossing the radius of a SVG circle?

Tags: svg

Suppose I have a SVG circle with a radius r. Now suppose I have an SVG line which starts at the center of the SVG circle. How can I determine the x2 and y2 coordinates of where it crosses the radius of the circle.

```
<line x1="500" y1="500" x2="300" y2="75" style="stroke:#156217;stroke-width:4" />
<circle cx="500" cy="500" r="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="transparent" />
```

Comment: This indeed might work, but I suspect that there is a much easier way. I'd really like to be able to draw the line using the angle from the center point, and have it stop at the circle.

Comment: Your question says you want to find the coordinates though. If you just want to draw a clipped line then it is, as you say, much easier. I've answered that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can clip the line with a clipPath. The use element allows us to point to the circle element we want to reuse for clipping.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
<defs>
  <clipPath id="cp">
    <use xlink:href="#c"/>
  </clipPath>
</defs>
<line x1="500" y1="500" x2="300" y2="75" style="stroke:#156217;stroke-width:4" clip-path="url(#cp)" />
<circle id="c" cx="500" cy="500" r="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

Comment: @Robert_Longson I had not heard of 'clipPath' before so I looked it up. This does solve the first part of my problem, how to stop the line at the circle. Now I need to know how to draw the line at an angle from the center, without worry about its end points (which of course are at the edge of the circle. I'm trying to create a hub-spoke kind of chart, each line starts at the center but ends at different points within and outside of a circle. I need this so I can make them clickable to display an info box (like on a map) with additional information.